# Why does the potentiometer have no effect on the output voltage here?

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, resistance, tri-state, 7400

I have the circuit below, where D and Q are input and output pins (respectively) of a 74373 octal D-type transparent-latch IC. As I vary the pot from 0-10k when D is high, the voltage goes high and changes only very little with the varying pot (\$ \Delta V=0.97\$). Why does the pot only affect the D input by a small amount? The chip is being powered by +5 V.

[image]

Comment: What voltage are you talking about? On `D` or on `Q`? Why would it affect it at all? What is this circuit is even supposed to do?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the voltage on Q

Comment: Why would it change anything? If the latch is ideal, it's output voltage will be constant.

Comment: The latch is currently set high, which, from my naive understanding, means that it is disabled and is not latching anything.

Comment: It doesn't matter high or low. It's an output, and you can't force a voltage on it in ideal case.

Answer (score 1):

You have the pot connected to the *output*.  The flip-flop changes its state based on its inputs, not the output.

It's hard to even guess what you think was supposed to happen.  All you are doing is changing the loading on the output.  However, with about 920 Ω lowest impedance you are putting on the output, it should still largely stay high or low according to the flip-flop logic.

Comment: I can only think this experiment is somehow intended to demonstrate the difference between current sink capability and current source capability for a 74 series device output. But who knows, it looks like a homework assignment anyway.

Comment: It is not a hw assignment, for starters. I am simply trying to learn circuits on my own and am going through a book I bought. There is a point in the book that asks why varying the pot here has no effect on the output.

Comment: It has no effect because a digital output is either high or low. Within the current sourcing or sinking capacity of the flop, the output voltage will remain fairly unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The 74373 has tri-state outputs. Pulling OUTPUT ENABLE high will tristate the outputs making them high impedance.*

- When the outputs are enabled the pot will make very little difference as the output under test will be pulled high or low by the output transistors.
- When the outputs are disabled you will see a variation in the voltage from about 0.5 V to 4.5 V as the outputs are, effectively, disconnected.
- The 1k resistors are there to limit the output current to a safe value if you try this with the outputs enabled.

Comment: One thing I didn't understand is why this is a tristate in the first place. If the output can either be high or low, that is 2 possible states. What is the 3rd state? Is the 3rd state the ability to vary the output with the potentiometer?

Comment: Tri-state outputs are used where multiple chips might drive the same lines but you don't want them fighting each other. e.g. If there are multiple memory chips capable of feeding data onto the eight data lines you enable the outputs on one at a time and it will pull the lines high or low depending on the binary value in the memory. The other chips will be tri-stated or disconnected. See http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_9.html part way down the page.